# Remove particular node in border pane in javafx

Tags: java, javafx-2

I have a border pane and there are components in its top, left and right side. I want to remove the components of its right side by using id of the borderPane through a mouse event. How do I do that?

Answer (score 8):

Just do

```
borderPane.setRight(null);
```

Comment: Am I the only one who gets ConcurrentModificationException here? Don't we need to use Platform.runLater? `button.setOnAction(e -> Platform.runLater(() -> borderPane.setRight(null)));`

Comment: `borderPane.setRight(null)` doesn't actually remove the child node from the `BorderPane`; you will still see this child in `borderPane.getChildren()`.Probably this is okay in most cases, but if you later wanted to `borderPane.setRight()` again to the previous child, you'd encounter an exception.

Comment: @LucasMorgan It will remove it. Sounds like you have something else wrong in your code.

Comment: You are correct. Haven't figured it out, but I definitely assumed incorrectly from a bad test scenario. Thanks!