# Changing a panel in javafx

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

This is like a sketch of my application. I have used SceneBuilder to develop the application. I have used `BorderPane` and placed two panels at right and left. I want to load different panels as per the button clicks and the panels are separate fxml files. How do I do that? I just want to replace the right panel not the whole scene.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove particular node in border pane in javafx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20882662/remove-particular-node-in-border-pane-in-javafx)

Answer (score 2):

Just load the fxml and set the side of the BorderPane as usual.

```
FXMLLoader  fxml = new FXMLLoader( .... );

Parent  leftSide = (Parent) fxml.load();

borderpane.setLeft( leftSide );
```